# Understanding Prolog exercise (removes all duplicates from a list)

Tags: prolog

I'm exercising for an exam and I'm having a hard time understanding the process of how Prolog works. Can someone please explain to me the process behind this exercise?

The question is:
Write a Prolog program that removes all duplicates from a list and returns the duplicate-free list.
For instance, given the list L1 = [a,b,a,c,a,a,b], the duplicate-free list is L2 = [c,a,b].
Note that the order of the elements in L2 does not matter.
You can use the built-in predicate member(X,L) to check whether X is a member in L

The solution is:

```
rmdup( [], [] ).
rmdup( [H|T], R ):- member( H, T ), !, rmdup(T,R).
rmdup( [H|T], [H|Rest] ):- rmdup( T, Rest ).
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Explaining how unification works, how Prolog seeks solutions, what backtracking is, why `!` is a thing, how recursion works, how removing duplicates works in detail is probably too much for one answer. It's three chapters worth of [LearnPrologNow](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pageid=online) (Unification and proof search, recursion and under Lists, recursing over lists). If you can narrow down what specifially you don't understand, it might help. Have you tried tracing the execution of that code to see how it runs?

Comment: Also there's 44 search results for ["Prolog explain recursion"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prolog+explain+recursion), 99 for ["Prolog remove duplicates"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prolog+remove+duplicates), 740 for ["how does Prolog work"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+does+prolog+work) on this site; you can't read all of them but quite likely there's a few explanations in the most upvoted ones ones which might help.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I will use the resources you gave me to see if I can understand it better!

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down, line-by-line, shall we?

```
rmdup( []    , []    ) .  % The empty list is unique by definition
rmdup( [H|T] ,  R    ) :- % For a non-empty list, though...
  member( H, T ),         % - Is the current item found later in the list?
  !,                      % - If so, eliminate the choice point (we don't want to follow the "unique" path
  rmdup(T,R).             % - Discard the current item and recurse down
rmdup( [H|T] , [H|R] ) :- % Otherwise (this list item is unique)
  rmdup( T, R )           % - prepend it to the result list and recurse down.
  .                       % Easy!
```

One could also write this without the cut, like this, which might make it easier to understand. It does, however, introduce a redundant `member/2` test:

```
rmdup( []    , []    ) .
rmdup( [H|T] ,    R  ) :-    member(H,T), rmdup(T,R) .
rmdup( [H|T] , [H|R] ) :- \+ member(H,T), rmdup(T,R) .
```

I have intentionally aligned the structures in the head of each clause because a lot of Prolog is about pattern matching.

Also note that the result list is built as an *open list*, where the end of the list is *unbound*. That open list will become a *closed list*, when the source list is exhausted and the result list is *unified* with the empty list `[]`. Until then `R` is a variable, and the result list gets constructed as a side-effect of unification in the head in the 3rd clause that handles unique items.

And finally, the order of clauses here does not really matter. You could switch the order up and it will still behave properly. This

```
rmdup( []    , []    ) .
rmdup( [H|T] , [H|R] ) :- \+ member(H,T), rmdup(T,R) .
rmdup( [H|T] ,    R  ) :-    member(H,T), rmdup(T,R) .
```

works, as does even

```
rmdup( [H|T] , [H|R] ) :- \+ member(H,T), rmdup(T,R) .
rmdup( [H|T] ,    R  ) :-    member(H,T), rmdup(T,R) .
rmdup( []    , []    ) .
```